# How to get excel popUp calendar?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel 2010 and found confused instructions to get popUp calendar in a cell or in a userForm.

```
File - Options - Add ins - Active Add-ins: 'Pop-Up Calendar is there
```

I download this Add-in from this site: http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm
Still, on loading a file, I get the message

```
Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine.
```

Alt+f11 - ToolBox - RightClick - Additional Controls - I can't see any Calendar or MonthView Control.
Somewhere I found that Access must be installed, but Access IS installed (office 2010 Pro).
I want the Calendar on a Cell (by click or rightClick) and in a userForm available also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Additional Controls list, search **Microsoft Date and Time picker Control 6.0 (SP6)**

Comment: ThankYou, edouard, but there is no such one in my Additional Controls list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and after much research on the internet, I managed to get this matter sorted out.
The fact is Calendar or MonthView Control has been removed from MS Excel 2010.
You have to download the Control and install it. Below is the download link

http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/MSCOMCT2.CAB

- Extract Both Files | the .inf file and the .ocx file
- Install | right-click the .inf file | hit "Install"
- Move .ocx file | Move the .ocx file to "C:\Windows\system32"
- Run CMD | Start Menu -> Search -> "CMD.exe" | right-click the icon | Select "Run as administrator"
- Register Active-X File | Type "regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\MSCOMCT2.ocx"
- Open Excel | Open VB Editor
- Activate Control | Tools->References | Select "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 2-6.0 (SP6)"
- Userform Controls | Select any userform in VB project | Tools->Additional Controls
  Select "Microsoft Monthview Control 6.0 (SP6)"
- Use 'DatePicker' control for VBA UserForm

Hope you get it right now, if not do let me know.